# Antisymmetric function with triangle inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking for a function $f : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the following properties:

- $f(x,y) = -f(y,x)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$,
- $f(x,z) \le f(x,y) + f(y,z)$ for all $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$.

Anybody has an idea about how the function looks like? Of course there are trivial solutions: $f(x,y) = g(y) - g(x)$, but how about the non-trivial answers?

Comment: I think you meant $f(x,y) = -f(y,x)$, otherwise $f \equiv 0$ does the job.

Comment: Yes, I have already edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: Every $\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ function $f$ may be written as $f(x,y)=\underbrace{\dfrac{f(x,y)+f(y,x)}{2 }}_{\text{symm part}}+ \underbrace{\dfrac{f(x,y)-f(y,x)}{2}}_{\text{antisymm part}}$ . If that helps.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin $f$ is already antisymmetric, and what about the triangle inequality?